# chassis fan running at full speed, fancontrol not working Ubuntu 20.04 Amd ASUS MB

Tags: kernel, 20.04, fan, amd-processor, fancontrol

I have tried to follow several methods to control my fans, nothing worked.
I have a M4A88T-M motherboard with a Phenom AMD processor and NVIDIA Quadro600 PCIe card.
I installed thermald, lmsensors, fancontrol, and Xsensors and Psensors so I can get a graphical reading of my fan speeds and temps.

I have added to /etc/default/grub

```
acpi_enforce_resources=lax
```

to get pwm to run but it didn't work.

```
sudo pwmconfig
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.
```

and I read in another post that either

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off" or

acpi_enforce_resources=no might work but I don't want to mess around with my kernel further without knowing what I am doing.

Another attempt:

```
sudo service kmod start
Job for systemd-modules-load.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

According to sensors-detect the 2 sensors:

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip`AMD Family 10h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `it87':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip`ITE IT8712F Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

I installed the following to modules:

```
cat /etc/modules # Generated by sensors-detect on Thu May 28 02:29:36 2020
# Chip drivers
it87
```

Another thing I tried:

```
sudo systemctl status fancontrol

    fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor pr>
         Active: inactive (dead)
      Condition: start condition failed at Thu 2020-05-28 02:36:07 EDT; 1h 5min ago
           Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
                 man:pwmconfig(8)
    systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in fan speed regulator being skipped.
    systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service:11: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/>
```

I am not sure how to proceed to create min and max fan speed depending on temp. or what would work in Ubuntu 20.04. I may install the XFCE desktop as well.

Comment: Is there anything in `/sys/devices/platform/it8*`?

Comment: There are other folders and uevent file in /sys/devices/platform/ but nothing labelled it8.

Comment: I turn off the desktop every night and this time it was quieter at boot-time, with no  changes to the bios!  It is second hand and I believe that might be mb issues...  It seemed quieter overall but would still like to adjust if possible.  Also hoping that adding fresh thermal paste to the CPU will help.

Comment: Anything in `/proc/acpi/ibm` ?

Comment: there is a blank file named wakeup in /proc/acpi but no ibm file- I don't think that there would there be IBM components for Asus/AMD board...

Comment: I don't know why it is called IBM, its just where the path lies to interface with the fans.  thinkfan and thermald will work for controlling the fans if that path existed.  fancontrol usually interfaces with /sys/devices/platform/